# "For educational purpose" or "for educational purposes"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, grammatical-number

When I was writing this:

> The university is for educational purpose.

everything was fine. But when I wrote this:

> The universities are for educational purpose.

The *Grammarly* said it's a mistake and "purpose" should be replaced by "purposes", but I don't understand. Does it have something to do with "universities"?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 'The university is for educational purpose' sounds fairly unnatural to a native speaker. The normal expression uses the plural form; a reasonable example would be '... the use of the internet for educational purposes.' The university is for educational purposes' may have the normal form, but sounds faintly ridiculous and clumsy.

Comment: Use "purposes" in both cases. But it seems a little redundant to say it at all: by definition universities are for educational purposes.

Comment: I have detected that you may be a non-native speaker. [ell.se] may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the singular, you should use an article:

- The university is for **an** educational purpose.
- The universities are for **an** educational purpose.

If you don't use an article, you should use the plural:

- The university is for educational **purposes**.
- The universities are for educational **purposes**.

---

Which of those four variations you use is a matter of context and personal opinion—although the plural noun is probably the more common use.

But a singular count noun requires an article or some kind of pronoun in front of it. (It's possible to interpret *purpose* here as a mass noun, but it would be somewhat unusual.)